# A bug of HttpWatch when use jquery.ajax method to send json request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, httpwatch

I am using HttpWatch 7.0.22 with IE 10.

When I opened HttpWatch, the jQuery.ajax call to a WCF service will fail with error:

> "Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
>   'MethodName'. The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any
>   information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty =
>   true)."

But it works all right if I didn't turn on the HttpWatch.

If I turn on the HttpWatch it will fail. Even if I close HttpWatch, it never work again.

Is this a bug of HttpWatch?

### ADD

I searched a bit, it seems not just 7.0.22 has such issue. Some 8.x versions also have it. And some people even claims that the HttpWatch officially respond with mail to admit it as a bug. But I don't see such mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems  to be a bug of HttpWatch 7.0.22. After I upgraded to 9.3, the issue is gone.